# don't know why but somehow substr() doesn't work in code??(php)

Tags: php, methods

recently I'm developing project via PHP, and today I faced a ridiculous situation, and couldn't get the reason still. So here's my problem

let's suppose that I have a string like this : `'myid(myname)'`

what  I wanted to get was myid and myname separately, so first I tried it with explode(), and I got result like below:

```
$order_identity= myid(myname);    
$idexplode=explode("(", $order_identity);
$idexplode= Array ( [0] => myid [1] => myname) )
```

It was good, but not satisfied, because I still have ')' after 'myname' so to get rid of ')'

I used substr() which is very basic built-in php method to slice string value.

```
$order_name = substr($idexplode[1],0,-1);
```

and I thought I've done quite good and logged it,However, contrary to my expectations.

I still got 'myname)' when I echoed "`echo $order_name`";  !!!

I never met problem like this before and do not know why this happened to me :/.

can you tell me what's going on here and how to solve my problem?
thx for reading, your help will be appreciated.

p.s I  already checked type and it was string! and also I checked if my php sever being lagged but it wasn't!!

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Does `$order_identity` contain whitespace at the end?

Comment: you were right there is whitespace in variables should've checked it frist  thankx!

Answer (score 1):

use this **$order_name - rtrim($idexplode[1],')')** Instead of substr()....you get what your want.....hope you got the answer....

Comment: thank you but I just tried it and it doesn't work either...

Comment: oh no worries, I do not know why but there is some whitespace in there so I used  $order_name = substr($idexplode[1],0,-6); and it worked! should've checked length of string earlier, sorry to waste your time but I appreciate your effort!

Comment: no issues......